# How to change a plugin display order in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using several wordpress plugin widgets for my pages and posts in wordpress. Now there is a problem regarding displaying the plugin widgets in correct order. The plugins i am using are `share juice pro plugin and outbrain plugin`. Now the outbrain plugin is displayed first and then the share juice pro plugin.

What should i do to change the display order?

Answer (score 0):

There is no interface for making this happens it seems. The only way to do it is to do it manually by editing the plugin file. You can find more details here: http://omeka.org/forums/topic/changing-display-order-of-plugins